# Calling a FusionTable marker icon from outside of the map

Tags: javascript, google-fusion-tables

I have a FusionTable that displays three different types of locations (Elementary Schools, Middle Schools, and High Schools), each with a different marker.  I have successfully created a map that shows all 3 and allows the user to toggle them on and off with:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="2" onclick="changeMap(this.value)" checked="checked" />Elementary Schools
```

Is there a way that I could have the marker that is used show next to the checkbox but before the name of the thing that it is marking?  I.e. it would display [ ] small_red Elementary Schools (with the small_red being an actual small red dot from the map)?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way I could find to do it was from this thread: 
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/fusion-tables-users-group/Zwoq9xivyXs

See Nick S. reply.  Just did a standard html IMG.  Would still be interested if there is another way to do this.